# android edittext

Tags: android

I have one edittext
EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

when i want to clear edittext i use et1.setText("");
but if i have to clear edittext one by one character from the last 
for this i have no solution can u pls give me solution

Comment: are you clearing in such way to have animate effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know about SubString?

```
String contents = et1.getText().toString();
et1.setText(contents.substring(0, contents.length()-2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know what you want to clear you can get the text from the edittext and then remove the amount of characters from the end using string.substring(0,numOfEND);

Answer (score 1):

If your editText has focus, then you can delete characters backspacing from the cursor like this:

```
if (et1.getSelectionStart() > 0) { //check that you are not deleting from the zero point
    et1.getText().delete(et1.getSelectionStart()-1, et1.getSelectionEnd());
}
```